# Why is cmake link_library replacing absolute path with "-l" for a single library?

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

I'm attempting to cross compile a program from x86_64 to arm. I'm running into a problem while linking which is caused by cmake.

```
# Toolchain file
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH <path/to/rootfs>)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX <path/to/stage>)
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE arm-linux-gnueabihf)

# CMakeLists.txt
find_library(LIB_X11 X11)
message("X11: ${LIB_X11}")
target_link_library(<my exe> ${LIB_X11})
```

CMake will print out the absolute path to X11 and all the other libraries I'm using

```
<path/to/my/rootfs>/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libX11.so
```

I expect when I link libraries to see in link.txt arguments like this:

```
-l<path/to/my/rootfs>/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libX11.so
```

However for some reason X11 (and only libX11) gets replaced with "-lX11" in cmake's generated link.txt. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html#overview

> There are some cases where CMake may ask the linker to search for the library (e.g. `/usr/lib/libfoo.so` becomes `-lfoo`), such as when a shared library is detected to have no SONAME field. See policy [CMP0060](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0060.html#policy:CMP0060) for discussion of another case.